# MySql LEFT JOIN within LEFT JOIN

Tags: mysql, join

I am trying to do the following MySql query for a search box. I am trying to return the "Album" info (Title etc) while including a thumbnail of the first image in that album. However, I have to look up two tables to get the image info. First, the `photos_albums` that contain all the images in that album, get the first image `ID` from that table, then look up that image info in the `photos` table. I believe the problem I am having, is that I need to tell the first LEFT JOIN to limit the query to 1, but I have had no luck doing this. I think I need to do a JOIN within a JOIN? Any help on this would be much appreciated.

```
SELECT albums.title, albums.title_url, photos.path, photos.medType, photos.vpath
FROM albums
LEFT JOIN photos_albums
    ON photos_albums.album_id = albums.id
LEFT JOIN photos
    ON photos_albums.photo_id = photos.id
WHERE albums.user = '$site_user'
AND (
    albums.title LIKE '$keyword%'
    OR albums.title LIKE '% $keyword%')
LIMIT 6
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try something like this

```sql
SELECT a.title, a.title_url, q.path, q.medType, q.vpath
  FROM albums a LEFT JOIN 
(
    SELECT pa.album_id, pa.photo_id, p.path, p.medType, p.vpath
      FROM 
    (
        SELECT album_id, MIN(photo_id) photo_id
          FROM photos_albums 
         GROUP BY album_id
    ) pa JOIN photos p
        ON pa.photo_id = p.id
) q 
    ON a.id = q.album_id
 WHERE a.user = '$site_user'
   AND (
         a.title LIKE '$keyword%'
      OR a.title LIKE '% $keyword%')
 LIMIT 6
```

Comment: Hello Peterm. Thanks for the help. Forgive me, but I am a little confused about the 'a.title', 'q.path' and 'albums a' etc. Are these just shorthand 'place holders' for my column names - or do I enter the query as you have it? Sorry - still learning here ;)

Comment: These are table aliases (just like column aliases). I like to keep them short as one or two letter short. I'd recommend to start from what I've suggested and then you can tweak it, rename aliases if you want...

Comment: That worked perfectly - thanks very much. I'll have to do some research on table aliases, as I have never seen them before. Again - I really appreciate the help.